# on_message event disables all the bot commands

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I have an on_message event to prevent users with "Muted" role from sending messages:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(ctx):
    muted=ctx.author.guild.get_role(673180122768998411)
    if muted in ctx.author.roles:
        await ctx.message.delete()
```

But with this event bot doesn't react to all the commands. They are not working.
Example command:

```
@client.command(passContent = True)
@commands.has_role("║Участники")
async def rank(ctx):
    return
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use this:

```py
await client.process_commands(ctx)
```

So, your event will look like this:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(ctx):
    muted = ctx.author.guild.get_role(673180122768998411)
    if muted in ctx.author.roles:
        await ctx.delete()

    await client.process_commands(ctx)
```